# Jenkins: trigger a downstream job

Tags: jenkins, automation, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I have 2 jobs on Jenkins: job A (the upstream job) and job B (the downstream job) that needs to be triggered after job A has finished.

I used to solve this problem with: *configuring Trigger parameterized build on other projects* 
set on job A and it worked perfectly fine.

The thing is, I have been told that I can not do any change to job A so I need to stop using the  *configuring Trigger parameterized build on other projects* from job A (which I added in the past).
Is there a way to configure something in job B that will trigger the job once job A is done?
I noticed there is an *Build after other projects are built* but when checking this box, job B never started...

Is there any other way (plugin or something else) that can help me define everything in job B?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally tried it, but there is **[URL Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin)**. According to the wiki page, it allows to monitor URL location for changes, and even inspect the elements of the page for changes.

For your `Job A` (that you can't change), you can still access it's status with links like:
`http://<serverurl>/job/<jobAname>/lastBuild/api/json`
or
`http://<serverurl>/job/<jobAname>/lastStableBuild/api/json`

You can change the `json` to `xml` too

Alternatively, if you don't want to get involved in parsing all that output, you use simply:
`http://<serverurl>/job/<jobAname>/lastBuild/buildNumber`
When the `Job A` finishes a new build, the content of the above address will change, and the `URL Trigger Plugin` on `Job B` would trigger it.